# Centering navigation elements in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I searched for the problem in other topics but none of given answers worked for me.
I have a navigation, which should have **Menu1-Menu4** centered and **Menu5** on the right side of the navigation.

https://jsfiddle.net/tbvcc6bj/

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Menu5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

.navbar .nav,
.navbar .nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
    vertical-align: top;
}

 .navbar-inner {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following for getting some menu items on the right

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" collapse="navbarProperties.isCollapsed">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#/routeOne">Route One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/routeTwo">Route Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/routeThree">Route Three</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```